# What are my odds of drawing the rest of my deck

Tags: probability, star-realms

Do to the deterministic nature of the game, if I have a decent memory I can easily know what cards are left in my deck, if not their order. I have two cards in my hand that let me draw a card (1 each) and I know there are 4 cards left in my deck, two of which will also let me draw a card. What are the chances I'll be able to draw my entire remaining deck?

Comment: This is a fairly simple probability problem... if I knew the rules of Star Realms. What are the card drawing rules?

Comment: Some cards will allow you to draw a card under certain conditions, for this question, you can take it as read that the condition is filled. Simply, you an draw 2 of the 4 cards remaining, and if any of the drawn cards let you draw a card you can continue to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

50%

Symbolizing the cards that give you a draw a D, and the cards that do not as N, there are 6 possible permutations of draw vs no-draw.

In each permutation, the second N card represents the farthest you can get through your deck on this turn.  I have bolded it for easier visibility.

DDN**N**

DND**N**

DN**N**D

NDD**N**

ND**N**D

N**N**DD

Comment: This could also be explained by defining any permutation that ends with a Draw card last as the fail condition.